# applicationWillResignActive dismiss keyboard iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

When an SMS is received during the use of my app, I would like for any open keyboards to be dismissed. How can I do that from applicationWillResignActive in my app delegate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement code like the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589598/how-to-react-to-applicationwillresignactive-from-anywhere/1523352#1523352). Have your view controllers register for `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`. When the notification fires,  call `resignFirstResponder`. That way you avoid tight coupling between your `UIApplicationDelegate` and your view controller. Assuming your view controller has a `UITextField` named `textField`:

```
- (void) applicationWillResign {
    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad { 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(applicationWillResign)
        name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
        object:NULL];
}
```

Comment: then how can I reverse the change made by applicationWillResign? Once the SMS is closed, how can I re-open the keyboard?

Comment: [self.textField becomeFirstResponder]

Comment: Yes, but where does that statement go?

Comment: I would probably put it in viewWillAppear in the view controller. If you want to, you could add an observer for UIApplicationDidBecomeActive in your view controller and create a method in your view controller to handle the notification.

Comment: I did not realize that UIApplicationDidBecomeActive is called here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a Swift 5 implementation try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("App moved to background!")
}
```

For more information please follow https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-detect-when-your-app-moves-to-the-background