# Objective c - Detect current view from appDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using modal segue (without navigation controller) to move between viewController A and viewController B like so:

```
viewA *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewA"];
[self presentViewController:first animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And to move back :

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now, I want to know from the AppDelegate whether A or B is the current view right now.
The problem is when I'm checking

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]
```

the answer is always view A - the first one.

I've tried to set the current view every time I'm using modal segue like so:

```
viewA *first = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewA"];
    [self presentViewController:first animated:YES completion:^
{
[[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:first];
}];
```

But it cause a few bugs (like unable to use "dismissViewControllerAnimated"),and it's impossible to work like that in every segue in a big project with many segues.

How should I work with that? And how should I detect the current view in more appropriate way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843411/getting-reference-to-the-top-most-view-window-in-ios-application)

```
UIWindow *topWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
    return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
}] lastObject];

UIView *topView = [[topWindow subviews] lastObject];
```

However, doing this logic here sounds like bad architecture. What is the reason for you needing to know which view is currently presented inside of your AppDelegate?

**Edit** It seems like you want to respond to the `applicationWillResignActive` event from your view controller. Use something like this in the your game view controller.

```
- (void) applicationWillResign {
    NSLog(@"About to lose focus");
}

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillResign)
     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
     object:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: I have a game.
The viewA is the main menu and viewB is the game itself.
I want to pause the game every time the app is moving to background (applicationWillResignActive).
so I need to know the current view to call the pause method or not (because if I'm at the main menu or something else I don't need to call the it).
this is one of the examples.
In all my apps I'm using only modal segue and when I need to call some methods from the appDelegate, I have to know what is the current view.
This is how I work, but maybe it's wrong. So, if I'm doing something wrong I would like to know :)

Comment: @AsiGivati That's a very real reason. A better solution is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589598/how-to-react-to-applicationwillresignactive-from-anywhere).

Comment: Awesome! working perfect with NSNotificationCenter :)

Comment: @AsiGivati [Also already answered, a lot of times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656367/is-nsnotificationcenter-removeobserver-in-arc-needed). Consult google a little more before asking next time.

Answer (score 0):

The appDelegate's window won't be equal to either view controller (viewControllerA or viewControllerB).  You can ask the window for it's root view controller...

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

if (appDelegate.window.rootViewController == viewControllerA) {
    // always true if you always start the app with viewControllerA
```

... and you can ask any view controller for the view controller it presented...

```
if (appDelegate.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController == viewControllerB) {
   // will be true if viewControllerA has presented viewControllerB
```

But this is a tricky game.  If, for example, viewControllerB presents some other viewControllerC, the condition above will continue to be true.

See the @Eric answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131205/iphone-how-to-find-topmost-view-controller) (not the accepted answer) for a way to find the topmost vc in general.